# Is there any method to get excel column numbers as dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have tried this code but it is not working can anyone help me to get out of this issue? Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ARC Performance Matrix.xlsx,Sheet1,skiprows=2,keep_default_na=False)

print(df)
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

**Note1**: There is a missed quote.

**Note2**: Use slash instead of backslash.

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/ARC Performance Matrix.xlsx","Sheet1",skiprows=2,keep_default_na=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: yes i have tried this but showing this error

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'Decimal' from 'decimal' (c:\Users\DELL\Documents\programs\decimal.py)
PS C:\Users\DELL\Documents\programs>

Comment: @krishna, This error is about missed importing module. So, check if the "decimal" module is properly installed. Using this command line: `pip list`